# Algebra: Big negative powers and numbers....

Tags: arithmetic

I have a problem with a mathematical problem that I know that I have to use some "power properties" but this problem confuses me and I can't solve it. Here is the problem:
$$
(-4)^{-60}  \cdot  (1{,}25)^{-40}  \cdot  10^{-41}
$$

Comment: I've assumed that "1,25" is continental notation for 1.25... let me know if you intended something different.

Comment: @user7530 Yep. That what i mean. But i live in Europe, Greece and we use  ,   and not .  In decadical numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the facts that $-4=(-1)\cdot4$ and $1.25=\frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: Ok. I will "play" with maths now a little bit. Thanks